# Statistics about HTML versions

Tags: html, statistics, version

There are various statistics on the web, about browser usage, OS usage etc.

Is there a statistics about HTML versions? Where we can see percentage of HTML 5, HTML 4.01, HTML 3.2 in certain month and see increasing number of documents in HTML 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could find these links:

http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/ml-html_transitional/4/all

http://try.powermapper.com/demo/statsversions.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It doesn’t really matter which DOCTYPE you use, as long as you use one. All HTML versions are [backwards compatible by design](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-design-principles/), so I’m not sure how this would be useful.

To answer your question though, you could use Blekko to grep the web for `<!DOCTYPE html>`: http://blekko.com/webgrep?page=view&id=596317f0c5088f34763e084129481a90

Comment: Except of course HTML5 isn't really backwards compatible except for browsers. All kinds of mark-up semantics have changed, including both narrowing and widening of meanings, so an author's intent can be lost if the version is unknown.

Comment: @Mathias It could be useful, because you can distinguish webpages that certainly `don't use` features of higher HTML versions and webpages that `may use` features of higher HTML versions.

Answer (score 1):

Powermapper claims to track this on their [HTML Version Statistics](http://try.powermapper.com/demo/statsversions.aspx) page.  As of Mar 2012, HTML5 is around 15%.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to derive that information from the browser usage. E.g. check which browser supports which html version and then search for browser usage by version.

http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=1&qpcustomb=1 (Browser usage by version).